# Bootstrap one element in row one

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to Angular code that loops through a list and creates rows of three using Bootstrap. My code is working except one element is always alone in the first row. It looks like this:

```
1
2 3 4
5 6 7
8 9 10
```

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10]" ng-class="{'row': 
$index % 3 == 0}">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        {{n}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the rows to end up like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

Comment: just need to change  $index % 3 == 0 to ($index+1) % 3 == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $index+1 instead of $index

```
  <div ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10]" ng-class="{'row':
   (($index+1) % 3) == 0}">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
             {{n}}
          </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you would want something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="n in array" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">{{array[$index]}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-if="array.length > ($index + 1)">{{array[$index + 1]}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-if="array.length > ($index + 2)">{{array[$index + 2]}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution. The first element in the array was still in its own row.

Comment: updated the answer, I read the question wrong, thought you want to acheive the first example given in question

Answer (score 0):

Then you could easily take `ng-class` to one depth below and then apply `col-sm-12` or `col-sm-3` on demand.

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10]" 
       ng-class="{'col-sm-12': $first, 'col-sm-3': !$first}">
        {{n}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10]" ng-class="{'row': 
$index % 3 == 0 && $index!=1}">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        {{n}}
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to apply another condition to check weather the number is one or not because the modulus of 1/3 is also zero.